# Probability question about meeting a woman who is a Hindu?

Tags: probability

I am learning about probabilities like joint and conditional probabilities and just recently learning about Bayes, and then this question came to my mind so I've been trying to figure it out:

How can I calculate the probability of meeting a Hindu Woman (in US)?

Do I need to figure out the probability of meeting a Hindu given that she is a woman, or a woman given that the person is a Hindu, or a person who is a woman AND a Hindu?  Can I even calculate all these probabilities?

I first tried to figure out prior probabilities but got confused, so instead tried to figure out the probability of meeting a woman, any woman, and I figured it's 50% because half US population is female.  But then I thought a woman means an adult, so the likelihood is probably lower. So maybe 40%.

Anyhow, then I looked up the numbers on Hindus and it's 2 to 3 million.  So let's say 3 million. That is one percent of US population.

So I guess this means I have data for p(H)=0.01 and P(W)=0.4

Sorry, for the mess of reasoning above, but I just wanted to show what I have been trying to do, but anyhow, I'm stuck.  Any help?

Comment: It seems that you must calculate $\Pr[W\cap H]$ using Bayes inference. However it is not clear how to evaluate such thing without more context.

Comment: Thank you.  But what kind of context?  I don't need exact numbers, I'm just trying to use probabilities in real life situations to see if I understand them.  I imagine if p(W) and p(H) were independent, then I could find the answer as p(W) * p(H), no?  But how do I determine if they are independent?  Because if they are not, I guess I have to figure out how to use Bayes.

Comment: As an aside... one percent is $0.01$.  A tenth of one percent is $0.001$.  Now... it may be reasonable to assume that gender is independent of religion in which case $Pr(W\cap H)=Pr(W)\times Pr(H)$, so if you meet a single randomly selected person from the population the probability that they are a woman hindu using your numbers would be $0.01\times 0.4 = 0.004$.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected that error

Comment: As for whether gender truly is independent of whether or not someone identifies as being Hindu, that again seems like it should be fine for an approximation and should be close. There are times and reasons why such an assumption would be invalid though. For an extreme case, suppose there is some religion who only accepts males as members and a tenth of the population identify as that religion, $R$.  In that case, it certainly wouldn't be true that the probability would be $Pr(W\cap R)=0.4\times 0.1=0.04$ since we know that there are no women members of that religion so it should have been $0$.

Comment: Oh I see.  So if this question was about meeting a woman who happens to have a high position in the temple (and assuming that men are more likely to get that position), I could not assume independence right?